Units for proper distance
The proper distance for a spacelike path $P$ between two spacelike-separated events is defined as
$$L=c\int_P\sqrt{\mp ds^2}=c\int_P\sqrt{\mp g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu}$$
assuming $(\pm,\mp,\mp,\mp)$ metric signature. I am bit confused why the integral should be multiplied by $c$. If $\sqrt{\mp ds^2}$ is measured in light years, then $L$ will be measured in light years squared per year? The linked page says that $\mp g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ is assumed to return time not distance. I don't get how it is possible.

Different authors use different conventions. The convention used on that page is explained on that page.

In the equation above, the metric tensor is assumed to use the +−−− metric signature, and is assumed to be normalized to return a time instead of a distance. The − sign in the equation should be dropped with a metric tensor that instead uses the −+++ metric signature. Also, the $c$ should be dropped with a metric tensor that is normalized to use a distance, or that uses geometrized units.

That is a bit of an odd convention, but it is clearly specified. You need to pay attention to the convention in use by any given author and be prepared to convert from one convention to another if needed.

If $\sqrt{\mp ds^2}$ is measured in light years

As specified, on that page it is measured in time (e.g. years)

Thanks, so if $\sqrt{\mp g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu}$ measured in years, then each element of g_{\mu\nu} is expressed in years squared per light years squared?

Not necessarily. Different authors will have different conventions there too. Some authors will put the units in $g$ and so $dx$ is dimensionless. Others will have units for $dx$ that vary by coordinate system or even within a coordinate system so that different components of $g$ may have different units.

My personal preference is (-+++) signature, $g$ has units of distance squared, and all coordinates are dimensionless.
